# Write a Python program to replace the last element in a list with another list? list is to be taken as an input

Tags: python

Write a Python program to replace the last element in a list with another list?
list is to be taken as an input.

```
Sample Input [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

```
Sample Output  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

i tried to take the input using `a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]`

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
b = [int(y) for y in input().split()]
a[-1] = b
print(a)
```

```
error in line 1 and 3 invalid litral
```

Comment: What are you inputting? what you have will only work if you input space separated numbers, eg `2 4 6 8`

Comment: you could just do somethin like
    a = [1,3,5,7,8,10]
    b = [2,4,6,8]
    output = a[:-1]+b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `eval() method` returns the result evaluated from the expression

```
a,b = eval(input()) # input() is returning str, with eval convert string into lists
# print (a) # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
# print (b) # [2, 4, 6, 8]

# use slicing to return list a without last element
# use operator + to conconate lists
result = a[:-1] + b

print (result)
```

output:

```
>>[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
>>> b = a[0][:-1] + a[1]
>>> b
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is also an option:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8]
a.pop() # get rid of last element
a.extend(b) # extend list a with b data
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not include commans (`,`) in your input if you are just going to use `input.split()`.

`input.split()` will split on spaces. To split on commas, you should use `input.split(',')` or `input.split(', ')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
li1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10]
li2 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
new_list = li1[:-1] + li2
print(new_list)
```